# Getting Wikipedia table results

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would need to collect in two different arrays the country-code top level domains (e.g. .ac) and the countries (please see the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains).

I tried to get the information that I need as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
with requests.Session() as s: # use session object for efficiency of tcp re-use
        s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        r = s.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        # print(soup.prettify)
tld_table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
links=tld_table.findAll('a')
```

but it gives me the wrong results when I consider `class: wikitable sortable`.

Could you please help me to figure it out?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the HTML you get from the request?

Comment: @AMC, Yes,I used google chrome inspect and it should be included in the wikitable sortable. But I am not totally familiar with html and web-scraping

Comment: _Yes,I used google chrome inspect and it should be included in the wikitable sortable._ My comment may not have been clear enough, there is a reason why I asked about the HTML **from the request**. What you see in the browser will often be different from what `requests` gets you.

Comment: I see. How could I choose a proper  request? Is there any way to understand before using it what I need to get from the website? I mean if I needed to scrape more websites to get information (e.g. collecting all images) used in those websites, should I do automatically or I would need to check the websites one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains")
tables[6] // is the table of the countries
```